# How do I remove 'Active Theme' section from Customizer?

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

I want to remove/disable the 'Active Theme' section from customizer. What could be the best way to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should do the trick:

```
function wpse293862_remove_themes_panel() {     
  global $wp_customize;

  $wp_customize->remove_panel( 'themes' );
} 

add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse293862_remove_themes_panel', 11 );
```

Comment: tested. It's working

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a panel completely use the `WP_Customize_Manager` class `remove_panel( string $id )` method. Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/

```
function themeslug_customizer_remove( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->remove_panel( 'themes' );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'themeslug_customizer_remove' );
```